# Laravel: Unable to add custom errors to validator after calling fails() or passes() method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-validation

After calling `fails()` or `passes()` method on the `Validator`, I'm unable to add `error` to the `validator` using `after` hook

```
$validator = Validator::make(
    ['name' => 'kanav'],
    ['name' => 'required']
);

if($validator->fails()){...} // I've some code around this

if($somecondition) {
    $validator->after(function ($validator) {
        $validator->errors()->add('name', 'Name Invalid');
    });
}

dd($validator->errors()->first()); //returns ""
// dd($validator->fails()); // returns true
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#after-validation-hook), try declaring the after hook before calling fails, like so

```
$validator = Validator::make(
    ['name' => 'kanav'],
    ['name' => 'required']
);

if($somecondition) {
    $validator->after(function ($validator) {
        $validator->errors()->add('name', 'Name Invalid');
    });
}

if($validator->fails()){...}
```

Comment: I already modified it this way but i was wandering what was causing the issue. May be a bug in Laravel.

Comment: That's not a bug, Laravel stores your after hook on the Validator instance and execute them when you call `fails` ;)

Comment: See here for more details https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php#L442